# Wordpress links not working after domain update

Tags: php, wordpress

I changed my wordpress from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`

Everything looks OK, until I click on an old post. It 404's.

If I change the root domain in the post to `domain1.com/posts/post1` it renders correctly. I've used the search and replace script to search for `domain1` but I see no results.

What can I do?

Comment: can you access the wp dashboard ? if yes go to the permalinks and reset links.

Comment: @ZaheerAbbas I did this to no avail

Comment: can you share link of your website so i can check ?

Comment: https://thesimpleengineer.com

Comment: I also cannot make new posts, they fail every time I try to publish

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess file. It should be in the root directory of your web server.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set your WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL variables in your wp-config.php.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://domain2.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://domain2.com');
```

WordPress stores these values in the database, but you can override them in your config file.

You may need to refresh your permalinks as well.

Settings -> Permalinks -> Save

Comment: Ok, I've overriden this in the file and also reset permalinks, still have the same issue